# Determine factor exponents

Tags: haskell, floating-point

I am getting compiler problems with this code, but don't really know why.

Any thoughts?

```
--divisorCount :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 
    divisorCount numer denom counter 
        | numer `mod` denom == 0 = divisorCount (floor(numer / denom)) denom (counter+1)
        | otherwise = -1
```

Comment: use `div numer denom` instead of `floor (numer / denom)`.

Comment: The base case should be `counter`, not `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numer` and `denom` have to be both an `Integral`, for `mod`, and a `Fractional`, for `/`. It's impossible.

However, that's easily fixed by converting `fromIntegral` before the division, or by `truncate`'ing (or using `round`, `ceiling`, `floor`), before the `mod`.

Or you could simply use `div` instead, like @Willem suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out

```
divisorCount numer denom counter
    | (q, 0) <- numer `divMod` denom = divisorCount q denom (counter+1)
    | otherwise = -1
```